# Orbeon form adding a autocomplete with existing itemset

Tags: orbeon

I want to add an autocomplete field into a Orbeon form. In the Control Settings I can choose an HTTP service which holds the itemset contains of the Resource URI.

How can I setup the autocomplete to instead an existing itemset from another dropdown field?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to say that, at least as of Orbeon Forms 2017.1, an autocomplete you add to a form you create in Form Builder can only get its values from the XML or JSON returned by a service. For reference, I've added a +1 from you on [request for enhancement 2380](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/2380).